# IIS: execute different URL rewrite rules depending on users

Tags: iis

My site https://example.com should execute a given URL rewrite rule (and thus act as a reverse proxy to internalServer1) for user1, and a different rewrite rule for user2 sending him to internalServer2.

Is this scenario possible with IIS8?

Answer (score 2):

No with URL rewrite as URL rewriter runs before any authentication happens in IIS, so these server variables are not set and hence cannot be used in rewrite rules.

Please note {REMOTE_USER} is empty due to that fact. (and it bring problem like illustrated [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120869/using-remote-user-in-iis-rewrite-module-2-0))

See that image to illustrate the process; from [there](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)

[image]

Comment: thank you for your useful elaboration. Might it make sense to add an "intermediate" reverse-proxy site behind the front-end reverse-proxy, with the sole purpose of evaluating {AUTH_USER} and conditionally proxy_pass to the appropriate internal server? I imagine that a simple PHP proxy might also work, and either way will carry a performance penalty.

Comment: @aag Hi, yes, never done it, but I would assume it would work. A proxy seem the only way to do, and not url-rewrite.